# LISP: How to output to console without the use of (Print) or (Format t) functions on a recursive function

Tags: recursion, lisp, clisp

This is my first post on here and please forgive me of any mistakes I may make.

My questions is the title above, is there any way to output data to the console in LISP (I'm using CLISP) at the end of a recursive function without using the (print ..) or (Format T ..) functions? This is an exercise that states we are only allowed to use the following functions: defun, cond, car, cdr, cons, append, list, and, not, or, <, >, <=, >=, =, eq, eql, equal, equals, +, -, *, /, mod

I have created a recursive function that creates a new list and I can output that list, but only if I wrap the recursive function inside a print function such as (print (myRecFunction)).  This does not meet the criteria of the exercise and thus is considered wrong. If I do not wrap this function around a print function, the console is just a blank line.

I am looking to see if anyone could provide a simple example of a list that is being outputted from a function being called (doesn't need to be recursive) that does not require it to be wrapped around a print function. I apologize if this is too vague, if more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be helpful to include the code you have already tried.

Comment: The Read-Eval-Print loop normally prints the value of whatever you type, you don't need to use `(print)` yourself.

Comment: There's no way to print without using one of the `PRINx` or `FORMAT` functions. The exercise makes no sense. Normally, functions don't do their own printing, they just return a value, and the caller prints it if that's what it wants.

Comment: The `trace` macro?

Comment: Can you provide a reference or a quote to the actual exercise, as well as the code of your recursive function?

Answer (score 1):

The REPL (Read Eval **Print** Loop) will print the top level results for you so the only thing you need to do is make sure your recursive function returns the value it should print and you get exactly what you ask for.

Here is a function that makes a palindrome:

```
> (defun magic-string (times string)
    (if (= 0 times)
        string
        (magic-string (1- times) (concatenate 'string string (reverse string)))))
magic-string
> (magic-string 3 "test")
"testtsettesttsettesttsettesttset"
>
```

Now all my lisp implementations print the result of both expressions. Don't yours?